# Angular Parse Value of Input programmatically in Controller - NaN

Tags: angularjs

I´m trying to get the value of my input for a further calculation. Actually, I get only a NaN. Could you pls give me hint? Thank you!

**HTML**

```
<input id="discount" ng:validate="number" ng-model="discount.show">
```

**Controller**

```
var discountPer = parseFloat(discount.show);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it...I´ve forgotten to set a scope

```
 var discountPer = parseFloat(discount.show);
```